# Developing webservices using SPRING Restful API

Tags: spring, rest

I want to develop a RESTful webservice sample application using Spring RESTful API. I am very much new to this field of spring as well as webservice.

Can anyone please suggest me any reference or website which has a step by step process for this ??

Thanx in advance for the helping hand.

Comment: I would recommend Spring in action 3rd edition as a good starting point.

Comment: i think this link - [Creating RESTful services](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch18s02.html) - (SpringSource docs) will help.